# How to Establish RFCOMM Bluetooth Connection From an iOS to android device

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth

I am creating an app which enables sending information between iOS and android devices via Bluetooth, **The app would not be submitted on app store**, so considering all options I found out that Apple didn't provide any such api, however using BluetoothManager Framework I was able to scan other devices and initiate a connection but can't get any further as there aren't any methods declared in header files for sending or receiving data, I do see a "BTSessionImpl" structure but don't know how to use it!

Please guide me If i am on right track or if I need to consider any other options.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to any other kinds of devices such as Android via Bluetooth on iOS.